# Which command should I use to build and push my entire dockerised app and its services to docker hub? docker or docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a little bit confused when using docker and docker-compose:

**With dockerfile** I can build, run, and push the docker application image to docker hub in order to allow other people to download and run it on their local computers.

**With Docker-compose** I can build, run and push the service image ( eg: redis, cassandra, etc)

**My concern:**

I got an application folder with the following files:

```
 - main.go  # the main app in Golang
 - Dockerfile # container definition file
 - Docker-compose.yml # contains all the services ( Redis and Cassandra)
```

**which command should I use to build and push my entire app and its services on the docker hub? docker or docker-compose?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One useful conceptual way to think about this is that the `docker-compose.yml` file specifies a set of `docker build` and `docker run` commands.  You cannot separately push the `docker-compose.yml` file to Docker Hub or other registries, and in a typical Compose setup there are references a number of standard images you don't need to push yourself (the standard Docker Hub `redis` and `cassandra` images will be fine no matter where you run them).

This means you need to do two things:

1. Push the application image (but not its public-image dependencies) to a registry; and
2. Publish the `docker-compose.yml` file or another way to run the combined application.

You can use [`docker-compose push`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/), but in a CI environment it's probably a little more straightforward to use [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) and [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/).  Mechanically they're not any different.

Make sure your image contains everything that's needed to run your application, up to external dependencies.  The ideal is to be able to `docker run` your application container, with `--net`, `-e`, and `-p` settings to configure it, but without separately providing the application code or a command.  In a `docker-compose.yml` file see if you can run it with only `ports:`, `environment:`, and `image:` (and `build:`).  Prefer a `CMD` in the Dockerfile to a `command:` in `docker-compose.yml`.  If you're bind-mounting host code into the container (unlikely for Go and other compiled languages) delete those `volumes:`.

A typical sequence for deploying things using Compose might look like:

```
here$ docker build -t me/myapp:20200525 .
here$ docker push me/myapp:20200525
here$ scp docker-compose.yml there:
here$ ssh there
there$ MYAPP_TAG=20200525 docker-compose up -d
```

Note that the only thing we directly copied to the target system is the `docker-compose.yml` that specifies how to run the image; we have not copied any application code or other dependencies, since that is all encapsulated in the image.

Comment: amazingly well explained. I will try this way